# How to use pip3 instead of pip2

Tags: python, pip, telethon, termux

i want to use Telethon but it says for my Python verison can you help i also want to use pip in 3.

Here is the error : `Package 'rsa' requires a different Python: 2.7.18 not in '>=3.5, <4'`

Comment: Did you try running `pip3`? Or if that doesn't exist, `python3 -mpip`? Or on Windows, `py -3 -mpip`?

Comment: it isn't working i am on termux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory imho, so you have to install, at least, python 3.5 in order to run that.
You can download it from here [Download python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

If you are using any other OS, you can search for it, and it should work fine.

Comment: i am on termux but

Answer (score 0):

[Termux uses apt and dpkg for package management](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Package_Management), so just enter `apt update && apt install python`.

You can use `python -V` to check afterwards.

```
$ python -V
Python 3.9.2
```